# functions in Module (Fortran)

Tags: function, module, fortran

I m learning Fortran. I'm following steven s chapra's fortran 95/2003 book. I am trying to use these two functions in a mod file instead of using it in the main program but this gives me error.

error #6401: The attributes of this name conflict with those made accessible by a USE statement.[Y]

error #6401: The attributes of this name conflict with those made accessible by a USE statement.[TAB]

```
module mymods

implicit none


!======================  Shared Data  ==========================

real*8, parameter :: pi = 3.1415926535897932_8
real*8, parameter :: ge = 9.8066500000000000_8, gc = 6.67408d-11


!====================  Subroutines  ============================
contains

real function y(p)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: p
    y= p+5.0
end function y


real function tab(t,n)
    implicit none
    real, intent(in) :: t
    real, external :: n
    tab = n(t)+t
end function tab

subroutine print_m(a)

        real, intent(in)  ::  a
        print*,a

end subroutine 

end module mymods
```

program:

```
program test
use mymods
implicit none
real :: a

real, external :: y
real :: tab

a = 2.5
call print_m(a)
a = tab (15.5,y)
call print_m(a)
end program test
```

I am a newbie in fortran. If i use the functions in program it's works fine
but If i use it as module it doesnt work.

Comment: Please post the full code sample as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, you may want to use a reference on how to get started with "modern fortran", for instance the [tutorials](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Tutorials) at the fortran wiki

Comment: Please take the welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Plask ask an actual question, I can't find any question in your post. Show us the complete code, all your error messages and the complete output.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here

Comment: Thanks a lot @HighPerformanceMark it worked !!

Comment: And now I found a question of which this is a duplicate, and whaddya know, I answered that one !

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me! I didnt see that question when I searched

Comment: It is pretty hard to find sometimes. I tried it and didn't find either.